# Update only that property not all model, django

Tags: python, django, web, backend

```
@property
def policy_escape(self):
    if self.date - datetime.date.today:
        self.status = 2
        self.save()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.counter = counter + 1
```

I have this logic for policies. For every policy created I want to increase a property nnumber(this is not exact my case).

I want when policy date is today date to change the status of that policy. But when I change it, the policy counter is increasing.

Can someone help me to update only status without updating other properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you would like to not increase the counter for that particular status update?

Comment: Exactly! I want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit the `update_fields`:

```
@property
def policy_escape(self):
    if self.date - datetime.date.today:
        self.status = 2
        self.save(update_fields=("status",))
```

However, the particular Python object would still have the changed counter. So you would have to avoid any other `save` calls on that object.

You could instead pass a custom `kwarg`:

```
@property
def policy_escape(self):
    if self.date - datetime.date.today:
        self.status = 2
        self.save(update_counter=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs, update_counter=True):
    if update_counter:
        self.counter += 1
    # ...
    super().save(*args, **kwargs):
```

Another way to avoid `save` being called at all is using `Queryset.update` instead:

```
@property
def policy_escape(self):
    if self.date - datetime.date.today:
        self.__class__.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(status=2)
        # self.status = 2  # if the current object should reflect that change
```